# How to execute a gradle task from a fe app

Tags: javascript, gradle

Hey I am wondering how to tackle the following issue, let's say I have a parametrized gradle task that I want to execute from a FE app, how would I tackle that issue. I was thinking of using a bash script that I can execute from the FE Web app, but I am open to suggestions.

I am hoping I will be able to run the task successfully.